# Is there an R function for collapsing characters into one cell if they have a matching character in another cell?

Tags: r, character

I have a dataframe with two columns of characters that looks like this:

| name | gene |
| --- | --- |
| GO:00001 | Gene_1 |
| GO:00001 | Gene_2 |
| GO:00002 | Gene_3 |
| GO:00002 | Gene_4 |
| GO:00002 | Gene_5 |

But I need to collapse the columns so that the "name" column isn't repetitive and the "gene" column contains each gene that matches to the same "name", separated by a comma and a space, like so:

| name | gene |
| --- | --- |
| GO:00001 | Gene_1, Gene_2 |
| GO:00002 | Gene_3, Gene_4, Gene_5 |

I have looked into the documentation for melt, collapse, and summarize, but I can't figure out how to do this with characters. Any help is much appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using dplyr:

```
> df %>% 
    group_by(name) %>% 
    summarise(gene = paste0(gene, collapse = ","))
# A tibble: 2 × 2
  name     gene                
  <chr>    <chr>               
1 GO:00001 Gene_1,Gene_2       
2 GO:00002 Gene_3,Gene_4,Gene_5
```

Using R base

```
aggregate(gene ~ name, FUN= paste0, data=df)
```